# JDBC MySQL OpenJDK

Tags: java, mysql

Я новичек в java, но уже задали написать небольшое приложение, которое бы работало с БД.
Я сижу на дебиан и установлен OpenJDK
Установил пакет libmysql-java, где-то прочел что именно его нужно устанавливать
Написал вот такой класс, чтобы проверить

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Connect {
  public static Connection con = null;
  public static void main (String[] args) {        
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "somePass";
              try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
                System.out.println("Driver loading success!");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", userName, password);
                System.out.println("Connected.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }    
  }
}
```

Выдает ошибку

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
  at Connect.main(Connect.java:10)
```

Собственно из текста ошибки ясно, что он не находит нужный класс.
На сайте мускула скачал mysql-connector-java-5.1.18, там внутри есть jar'ский файлик и папка src, в которой можно обнаружить com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Но что с ними делать, куда пихать?

Заранее спасибо

## to Shamanis

Установил из репозитория sun-java6-jdk, делаю вот так в консольке

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/javac Connect.java //нормально, без ошибок
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java Connect
```

Та же ошибка:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

А, и:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -version
```

выдает 1.6.0_26, это нормально?

## 2 All

Скопировал jar и папку Com во все папки, куда догадался, типа lib, ext и тд.
Заработало
Всем спасибо

Comment: может проблема с JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Как изменить в дебиан?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте просто mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar или как он у вас называется, подключить к проекту и всё заработает ;)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как с OpenJDK, отказался от него примерно месяцев восемь назад. Использую sun-java6-jdk под тем же Debian'ом. Ни каких проблем с драйверами не возникает, достаточно просто сделать

```
import java.sql.*;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
db = DriverManager.getConnection(mysql_url, mysql_user, mysql_pass);
```

Да, кстати, в Debian есть пакет libmysql-java, описание которого гласит "Java database (JDBC) driver for MySQL"

Answer (score 0):

Этот jar файл, Вы можете либо явно подключить к проекту - должно быть, что то вроде Java Build Path - в который Вам необходимо добавить этот jar, и разрешить проекту его использовать. Другой способ, добавить jar в используемые библиотеки java, что то вроде jre/lib/ext, jre[version]/lib/ext. Так же на разных платформах есть возможность прописать [classpath](http://www.google.ru/search?aq=1&oq=class+path&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=classpath+java)

Comment: Установил пакет libmysql-java

Насколько я понял установил ТС из дистрибутива, насколькоя  помню, когда ставишь из дистрибутива никаких проблем нет и быть не может...

Comment: Хотите сказать, что java - сама догадывается куда что система установила? Тут проблема с jav'овским драйвером работы с БД, а не использованием библиотек. jave всегда нужно ткнуть где искать jdbc - драйвер, если приложение собирается работать через него.

Comment: конечно нет, но система пишет libmysql в classpath сама, в связи с чем достаточно просто import'a.

Возможно ошибаюсь - писал на java под mysql довольно давно